# C - Pthread_cond_signal - Signal longest waiting thread

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

In the pthread library, is there an easy way to specify conditions on which thread to wake up first, if multiple threads are waiting on the same condition variable?

For example, say I have 3 threads waiting on a condition variable, and when I call pthread_cond_signal, I want to wake up the thread that waited first (in otherwords, the thread that has been waiting for the longest period of time).

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? From what I can see in my code, pthread_cond_signal just signals one of the threads that is waiting, in no specific order.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yes, this should be done with ticket-locks. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticket_lock

an example could look like that

```
int current_waiting_thread_ticket = 0;
int max_waiting_thread_ticket = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex; //initialize somewhere
pthread_cond_t cond; //initialize somewhere

void lock() {
     int local_ticket;
     pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

     // get current ticket
     local_ticket = max_waiting_thread_ticket;
     // set next ticket
     max_waiting_thread_ticket++;

     // wait until the local ticket is ready
     while (current_waiting_thread_ticket != local_ticket) {
         pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
     }


     pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void unlock() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    // next ticket is ready
    current_waiting_thread_ticket++;

    // wake up all waiting threads
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```